# multiple statements in an inline if

Tags: angularjs, conditional-operator

Is it possible to have multiple statements in an inline if statement in an AngularJS expression? For example, the following fail:

```
ng-change="someCondition() ? doA(); doB() : doC()"
ng-change="someCondition() ? doA(), doB() : doC()"
```

This can be done as follows:

```
ng-change="someCondition() ? doA() : doC(); someCondition() ? doB() : ''"
```

But that's ugly, calls someCondition() twice, and screams to be done in a controller. Is there any way to get the first examples to work?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You shouldn't do that much logic in the dom. Move it all to a function and just call that function. Keep the js in the dom simple.

Comment: @DigitalFiz I agree, but I feel like it would be easy enough to read (with an input with ng-model="email" and a checkbox with ng-model="emailOptOut")
emailOptOut ? emailCache = email, email = undefined : email = emailCache

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular expressions are limited to simple expressions. Anything more complicated may be rejected by parser and error will be thrown. Read about differences between [Angular Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) in documentation. Namely:

- No Control Flow Statements: You cannot use the following in an Angular expression: conditionals, loops, or exceptions.
- No Comma And Void Operators: You cannot use `,` or `void` in an Angular expression.

etc.

The best thing you can do is to create a function in controller that will combine `doA` and `doB`. Not only it will make Angular parse happy, but the code itself will become cleaner and simper to read. After all this is template, it's better to keep it simple.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that about the prohibition about using comma or void (or about RegEx's or filters.) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your first example is not valid javascript.
Your second example contains `,` which cannot be in any angular expression (not sure if valid javascript or not).

Depending on your use case you can sometimes get it to work using `&&` and `||`.

However, code in templates is still code. Try to make it readable. If you can't make it readable, extract it into a function in your controller.

```
ng-change="onChange()"
```

Comment: doA() could release a truthy or falsy value, so if I were to go this route (which is clever, and I like), I'd have to do 
ng-change="someCondition() ? (doA() && 0) || doB() : doC()"

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below scenario:::

use the () in multiple statements

ng-change="someCondition ? (doA(), doB()) : doC()"

ng-change="someCondition ? (doA(), doB()) : doC()"

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this in **Angular 8** with **ternary operator**

```
<input 
maxlength="{{memberProofForm.proofTypeId === 1?16:(memberProofForm.proofTypeId === 2?10:(memberProofForm.proofTypeId === 3?15:77))}}"
name="proofIdNumber" 
required 
type="text"
[(ngModel)]="memberProofForm.proofIdNumber">
```

It will work like this

```
if(memberProofForm.proofTypeId === 1){
    return 16;
}
}else{
    if(memberProofForm.proofTypeId === 2){
        return 10;
    }else{
        if(memberProofForm.proofTypeId === 3){
            return 15
        }else{
            return 77;
        }
    }
}
```